# How do I perform a conditional aggregation by ID without including the particular date of the row & specific date range (date minus days) in R

Tags: r

How do I perform a conditional aggregation by ID without including the max date and criteria of specific date range such as date minus certain days

QUESTIONS # A.1, A.2 and B:

INPUT Data = o2i

```
ID  date    event_p event_b
1   8/7/2016    1   0
1   8/1/2016    1   0
1   8/1/2016    1   1
2   7/28/2016   1   0
2   8/7/2016    1   1
2   7/29/2016   1   1
3   7/10/2016   1   0
3   7/7/2016    1   1
3   7/14/2016   1   1
4   8/24/2016   1   1
4   8/26/2016   1   1
```

Solution A.1) I would like to restrict the sum to only add up count of those events that have happened in 7 Days before the date mentioned
in the Date Column (per user ID). 
Note: NOT including the Date (but go back upto 7 days before the Date).
Note: if record of (Date-7 Days) does not exist then still the logic is same.

A.1 - OUTPUT Expected:

```
ID  date    event_p
1   8/7/2016    2
1   8/1/2016    0
2   7/28/2016   0
2   8/7/2016    0
2   7/29/2016   1
3   7/10/2016   1
3   7/7/2016    0
3   7/14/2016   2
4   8/24/2016   0
4   8/26/2016   1
```

Note: Here 8/1/2016 had two rows in input file (on same date) but in Output it is displayed as one. This is preferred, but if two rows are displayed, that is also fine.

Solution A.2) Instead of summing by event_p (for past 7 days), and event_b separate, Is there a way there is a way to write code so that both event_p and event_b are aggregated, as per the same logic ?

A.2 - OUTPUT Expected:

```
ID  date    event_p event_b
1   8/7/2016    2   1
1   8/1/2016    0   0
2   7/28/2016   0   0
2   8/7/2016    0   0
2   7/29/2016   1   0
3   7/10/2016   1   1
3   7/7/2016    0   0
3   7/14/2016   2   1
4   8/24/2016   0   1
4   8/26/2016   1   1
```

Note: Here 8/1/2016 had two rows in input file (on same date) but in Output it is displayed as one. This is preferred, but if two rows are displayed, that is also fine.

Solution B) I would like to sum to count of those events that have happened before the date mentioned in the Date Column (per user ID).
Note: NOT including the Date (but go back upto "all" days before the Date)
Note: if record of (Date-7 Days) does not exist then still the logic is same.

WHAT I TRIED:
I have researched and looked at this site, and tried to write the code almost for a week and closest i could get is via this codes.

My TRY A.1:

```
    # convert factor to POSIXlt
o2i$date <- as.POSIXlt(o2i$date, format="%m/%d/%Y")
class(o2i$date)
o2i$date
o2i

# convert factor to date
o2i$date <- as.Date(o2i$date)
class(o2i$date)

# Aggregation Option 1
cum7_event_p <- aggregate(event_p~ID+date, subset(o2i, date < max(o2i$date) & date >= (o2i$date)-7),sum)
cum7_event_p


# Aggregation Option 2
cum7_event_p <- aggregate(event_p~ID+date, subset(o2i, date < max((o2i$date)-1) & date >= (o2i$date)-7),sum)
cum7_event_p
```

WHAT I GOT FOR A.1)

```
ID  date    event_p
3   7/7/2016    1
3   7/10/2016   1
3   7/14/2016   1
2   7/28/2016   1
2   7/29/2016   1
1   8/1/2016    2
1   8/7/2016    1
2   8/7/2016    1
4   8/24/2016   1
```

Note: It is counting the events on the particular date as well.. For example, on 8/1/2016 it is showing sum of 2. But as per logic it should show count as "0" , because it is count of 7 days (before that date - not including the date) ...and on 8/7/2016 it should show count of 2.

My TRY A.2:

```
    ## All Event Aggregation ##
cum7 <- aggregate(o2i[,3:4], o2i[, c(1,2)], data=subset(o2i, date < max(o2i$date) & date >= (o2i$date)-7), sum)
# Error: Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : invalid 'type' (list) of argument

cum7 <- aggregate(o2i[,3:4], o2i[, c(1,2)], sum)  # Does not include the Logic of "Calling the Date (every date - per ID) and calling it a Max Date, while counting)
cum7
```

WHAT I GOT FOR A.2

```
ID  date    event_p event_b
3   7/7/2016    1   1
3   7/10/2016   1   0
3   7/14/2016   1   1
2   7/28/2016   1   0
2   7/29/2016   1   1
1   8/1/2016    2   1
1   8/7/2016    1   0
2   8/7/2016    1   1
4   8/24/2016   1   1
4   8/26/2016   1   1
```

Note: I am not sure how to write the best code to incorporate the (NOT including the particular date - and summing for either 7 days before that date .. and/or...all dates before that date).

I hope I was clear in explaining my problem and expected output. If someone writes a function to solve, I would very thankful if you can please kindly write few more lines of explanation no how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't find an elegant way of doing this. I'd just create a window function that takes date and events columns together, and outputs desired outcome. You can use dplyr to apply the function for each ID by doing group by.

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

myfun <- function(dates,events){
  ct <- rep(0,length(dates))
  for (i in 1:length(dates)){
    ct[i] <- sum(events[between(dates,dates[i]-7,dates[i]-1)])
  }
  return(ct)
}

dt <- read.table('testdata',head=T)
output <- dt %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(parse_date_time(date,c('mdy')))) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(summary_event_p = myfun(date,event_p), summary_event_b = myfun(date,event_b)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  distinct(ID,date,summary_event_p,summary_event_b)

# # A tibble: 10 × 4
#      ID       date summary_event_p summary_event_b
#    <int>     <date>           <dbl>           <dbl>
# 1      1 2016-08-07               2               1
# 2      1 2016-08-01               0               0
# 3      2 2016-07-28               0               0
# 4      2 2016-08-07               0               0
# 5      2 2016-07-29               1               0
# 6      3 2016-07-10               1               1
# 7      3 2016-07-07               0               0
# 8      3 2016-07-14               2               1
# 9      4 2016-08-24               0               0
# 10     4 2016-08-26               1               1
```

testdata file is just a text file of copied contents of your data. I used a *lubridate* function to just clean up the date format in your raw data.

Comment: Thank you Julius.. very well thought and precise answer. The solution works great. I would not join the result (output) with initial data frame by ID and Date. Most likely left outer join.

Comment: I mean, I would NOW join the result (output) with initial data frame by ID and Date. I hope this question serves as help to all ppl who want to calculate number of times any event happened, (before certain date, and not on that date).. Most likely left outer join.